# PHP mcrypt AES encryption wrapper

Tags: php, security, cryptography, aes

There are two keys: the main is aes128 and the second is XTEA, used just for randomization of data inside the AES. Randomization is done with secret random key that is not know even if someone knows exactly what is encrypted. Also the key is produced by doing hash many number of times and this hash is salted with the iv so it is not possible to make a dictionary attack with precomputed hashes.

```
function aes128ctr_en($data,$key,$hash_rounds = 0) {
    //iv is created
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16,MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    //internal secret random string is created so no one knows what
    //is exactly encoded by main cipher
    $xtea = mcrypt_create_iv(16,MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    //password is hashed in many rounds to prevent dictionary attack,
    //hashing is done with individual iv for hmac so it make no sense to use
    //precalculated hashes
    for($i=0;$i<=$hash_rounds;++$i) $key = hash_hmac('sha256',$key,$iv,true);
    //string is randomized for use in aes, so no one knows what actually will be encoded
    //this is not actual encoding so password is stored inside with xtea encoded string,
    //second half of this password is used as IV for xtea
    //again: THIS IS NOT ACTUAL ENCODING
    $data = $xtea.mcrypt_encrypt('xtea',$xtea,$data,'ofb',substr($xtea,8));
    //hash is added to check if return string is really what we looked for,
    //must match with string on decoding
    $data = hash('md5',$data,true).$data;
    //actual encoding, IV is prepended to encrypted string
    return $iv.mcrypt_encrypt('rijndael-128',$key,$data,'ctr',$iv);
}

function aes128ctr_de($data,$key,$hash_rounds = 0) {
    $iv = substr($data,0,16);
    $data = substr($data,16);
    for($i=0;$i<=$hash_rounds;++$i) $key = hash_hmac('sha256',$key,$iv,true);
    $data = mcrypt_decrypt('rijndael-128',$key,$data,'ctr',$iv);
    $md5 = substr($data,0,16);
    $data = substr($data,16);
    if (hash('md5',$data,true)!==$md5) return false;
    $xtea = substr($data,0,16);
    $data = substr($data,16);
    return mcrypt_decrypt('xtea',$xtea,$data,'ofb',substr($xtea,8));
}

$key = 'suPer_secret aAnd L10ng ppswrd$%';
$encrypted = aes128ctr_en('the bomb will blow up at 1 pm',$key,12345);
echo aes128ctr_de($encrypted,$key,12345);
```

I really don't have knowledge to make it better. I'm not that educated in all this to read RFCs and make algorithms out of it. I'm also constrained to methods that are precompiled in core PHP binary as I want these methods to be able to run on remote servers.

Comment: I hope this is the last of your "I wrote some algorithm and don't know exactly how it works, but tell me if it is secure" questions. At the very least you could have used test data to compare the output of your unreadable functions to a reference implemention like openssl.

Comment: take sha256, md5, xtea, and aes-128, place into a blender with some cool random bytes, and press the liquefy button. Pour the results out onto Stackoverflow for analysis.

Comment: Yes, this is last as I do not have knowledge to improve it. And second to Greg - WHAT random bytes ? Are there any arbitrary random bytes ? For example sha256 is used because it produces key lenght that match what is needed for aes. MD5 is only for checking if password is ok. XTEA is chosen because it is a very simple algorithm and it is not used for actual encoding. Again - whats wrong ? All I try is to make secure encryption by using what I have available in basic configuration of PHP.

Comment: And again to first comment. How I'm supposed to not know how this works since I WROTE it ? Did you even read the code ? Where I have written that I do not know how it works. What I do not know is if I'm using all the cryptographic methods in correct way so security is not undermined.

Comment: There is no way to tell if you chained the crypto functions in the right fashion. But you very much succeeded at obfuscating the processing logic. Which in turn is the reason for nobody bothering to analyze it. - If you want sensible comments, you should first post sensible code. Add comments, and split up your spaghetti code into well-named functions. - And instead of reposting code variations without substantiated change explanations, add a bounty to your question. - Second tip again: just compare your output to a well-known reference implementation. http://google.com/search?q=php+aes+class

Comment: I added comments to first function, second is basicaly doing the same but vice versa. And what spagetthi code ? There are only TWO functions written by me, rest is PHP (how I'm supposed to name php function myself?) and couple of variables, and those two functions are well named.

Comment: You should read [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: Give me one thing that is obscure here or you do not know for why is something used.

Comment: Well, the comments do very much improve this question. Spend your reputation on a bounty now and it's likely to get answered instead of closevoted. - It's even obvious now why the first function is a blob instead of being split up into the three subparts (hashing, shuffling, encryption stage). - At the very least it looks like a plausible approach. Yet I'm not stating this as answer, but to make it go away faster. Also consider that while the algorithm might be ok; running this in a PHP runtime ensures that the plain $key, $iv and $xtea variables will remain somewhere in memory on script exit.

Comment: Safe for what? What are you trying to achieve? What is your threat model? Why have you chosen the algorithms and compositions that you have? Why are the existing compositions of algorithms unsuitable for your purposes?

Answer (score 8):

You should use a key strengthening function like PKBDF2, scrypt or bcrypt to generate a key from the password.
The part with XTEA is useless: you're relying on security through obscurity.
You shouldn't hash before encrypting if you want to ensure the data has not been tampered with. Use HMAC SHA-256 on the encrypted data.

And finally: don't write your own crypto algorithm. Use well known and audited solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The basic answer is: No

Where is your random seed being generated from? (Oh wait, you are not using a random see - seriously big issue #1) Where it is being stored? What cryptographic symmetric ciphers are being used to generate your seed.

You expect the method you are using to be secure? You expect your server to never be compromised?

Failure to apply systematic cryptographic principles to the very basic of what you appear to be trying to do (Security through Obscurity) will always result in a failure of your cryptographic procedures because you fail to understand the necessary principles that need to be applied.

All I see is a whole lot of code designed to do one thing, yet is 100% at risk because you have failed to do other things that are necessary to the process of data encryption.

All that said, it would be very easy to produce something more secure than your 33 lines of code.

But first you need to learn the basics. After that, start looking into using `openssl_public_encrypt()` and `Crypt_Blowfish()`.

In about 8-10 lines of code you can have a solid cryptographic procedure that will be much more secure than your `StO` method that you are attempting here - and use methods that are time-proven to be unbreakable by all modern standards within the RAT (Reasonable Amount of Time) factor.

Comment: WHAT 33 lines of code ? the encoding part is only 6 lines, what are you talking about ?, Second - didn't you see MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM ?

Comment: Regardless of it being 6 lines or not, the code still fail the very basic of cryptographic methodology. Hard-coded seeds are never - and never will be - secure.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what "hard coded seed" means in this context ? I'm generating one public seed that seves as IV for crypt and one secret that is used to randomize string that is inside.